# Import of large files with dependencies into REST service

Tags: java, spring, performance, concurrency

Suppose there is a REST service capable to import large files containing assets.

Thoses assets could be duplicated to each other, also assets could create another entities so there are validations to check for a duplicates, and there are some dependencies between imports, so that it has to be checked across all current imports and already existing imports.

There is some processing logic for the assets before being saved, import of those files takes around 3-4 minutes. All assets are saved just after the processing has being done.

Could somebody advise what is the best way to handle concurrent issues from the perspective of having the best performance possible in such system?

Answer (score 3):

Reactive Programming is currently a good approach to get great performance in web applications. 
Have a look at this article about reactive programming and how it addresses performance issue: 
 https://blog.redelastic.com/what-is-reactive-programming-bc9fa7f4a7fc

Since you are using Java and Spring, Spring Webflux could be your way to start reactive programming. Have a look at this tutorial: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux 
This tutorial has it's focus on communication between client and server with REST. But reactive programming addresses also the processing of received data on server side, for example by interacting with the database in a reactive way.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Batch](https://docs-stage.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index.html) has the capability of [parallel processing](https://docs-stage.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html).

The framework is used for ETL processing

The job can be launched asynchronously by the controller after receiving the assets or it can be delayed - [natively](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) or using some other scheduler like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Apache Spark via Apache Livy which provides REST API interface for the Apache Spark. Apache Spark's ability on processing batch data, identifying duplicates is robust and it uses RDD/DataFrame for faster processing.

[https://dassum.medium.com/apache-livy-a-rest-interface-for-apache-spark-f435540e26a9][1]